# Not able to increase number of column in datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

I am using this default code of datatable [@fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/learner001/64Lz4cwx/)  But i am facing 2 issues,

1) When i am trying to increase the number of column, the whole css gets disturbed, and the pagination,search, number of records gets disappeared

2) in responsive view, with the help of scrollbar i can view the data horizontally and vertically but i am not able to see all the headers

Can anyone please tell how to solve these 2 issues

code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css"/>

<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
    "scrollY":        "400px",
    "scrollCollapse": true
    } );
    } );
</script>
```

Comment: no, css will only get disturbed when there will be not matching columns so if you are increasing column in one table, make sure you are increasing in every table. see https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/64Lz4cwx/2/ i have increased 1 column in every table and its working fine.

Comment: can you show your css file?

Comment: @SumanKalyan its related to datatable and bootstrap which is added in fiddle.

Comment: @Leo the lion k, i understood about that part, few of my values were missing so i could be the issue, but what about the responsive view

Comment: @Sam check this one https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/64Lz4cwx/4/

Comment: @Leo the lion thanks its working

Comment: My pleasure..but still working for better solution then this but its useful for  you then go with it :)